# Javascript block or slow down the browser. How to prevent alert or speedup script

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have a datatable with a lot of rows need to be exported in excel.
In my example I use only 500 rows, but in a real environment I have > 2000 rows.

UPDATE: added blockui to alert the user: https://jsfiddle.net/j2fug3ax/

Now, when rows are exported with the button in excel, there is a script that read each row to manipulate data and set it compatible with excel (formats, alignment, cell height, newline, ...)

Here the piece of code to edit rows:

```
           //need to change double quotes to single
           data = data.replace( /"/g, "'" );

           // replace &
           data = data.replace( /&/g, "&amp;" );

           // replace p with br
           data = data.replace(/<p[^>]*>/g, '').replace(/<\/p>/g, '<br>');

           // replace div with br
           data = data.replace(/<div[^>]*>/g, '').replace(/<\/div>/g, '<br>');

           data = remove_tags(data);



           //split at each new line
           splitData = data.split('<br>');

           //remove empty string
           splitData = splitData.filter(function(v){return v!==''});

           data = '';
           for (i=0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
                    //add escaped double quotes around each line
                    data += '\"' + splitData[i] + '\"';
                    //if its not the last line add CHAR(10)
                    if (i + 1 < splitData.length) {
                        data += ', CHAR(10), ';
                    }
           }

           //Add concat function
           data = 'CONCATENATE(' + data + ')';
           return data;
```

This code slow down the script and an alert appear on the browser to BLOCK or WAIT....
It is not very elegant, so, is there a way to prevent this alert or speedup my code?

Manipulation in my example is not necessary cause i set dummy data, but in a real environment I need it.

Answer (score -1):

So just a suggestion:

> Why not do it server-side?

Processing a large amount of data client-side is a bad choice. You are always dependent on the resource capacity of the client's system. Javascript as-is not a good option of compute intensive operations or data crunching.

**Solution**

Send your page size and page number via an API to the server. Query your table and create the excel/csv on the server side. Return the generated file in response for your UI to download it on the client's system.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, i don't want to reinvent the wheel. Datatables offer already a way to export in excel so i'd like to use it.

Comment: If your database allows you for the same without much hassles, by all means :)